# Program to count the number of 5 digit numbers divisible by 3 and not having 6,7,8 and 9 in them

Tags: c++

I've written a code that should print all the 5 digit numbers(without the digits 6,7,8 and 9 in them) divisible by 3 and count how many such numbers exist. I get no error when I compile it, however when I run it, I get no output.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a,b,c=1,temp;

  for(a=10002; a<=55554; a=a+3)
  {
    temp=a;
    while(temp>0)
    {
      b=temp%10;
      if(b!=6&&b!=7&&b!=8&&b!=9)
      {
        temp=temp/10;
        c=c+1;
        cout<<"   "<<a;
      }
    }
  }
  cout<<"\n\n\n"<<c;
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: move `temp=temp/10;` outside the `if` - you really should be learning to use a debugger to step through your code

Comment: Aside: `if(b!=6&&b!=7&&b!=8&&b!=9)` can be expressed more succinctly as `if (b <= 5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get no output.

This is because

> ```
>     temp=temp/10;
> ```

must be done in all cases, move the line to have for instance

```
while(temp>0)
{
  b=temp%10;
  temp=temp/10;
  if(b!=6&&b!=7&&b!=8&&b!=9)
  {
    c=c+1;
    cout<<"   "<<a;
  }
```

else if `(b!=6&&b!=7&&b!=8&&b!=9)` is false *temp* is unchanged and `while(temp>0)` turns forever

Note also the `cout<<"   "<<a;` is wrongly placed because you need to write/count only if *all* the conditions are respected, not only one

Out of that because *b* values from 0 up to 9 the test `(b!=6&&b!=7&&b!=8&&b!=9)` is equivalent to `(b < 6)`

So a solution can be :

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a,b,c=1,temp;

  for(a=10002; a<=55554; a=a+3)
  {
    temp=a;
    while(temp>0)
    {
      b=temp%10;
      if (b >= 6)
        break;
      temp=temp/10;
    }
    if (temp == 0) {
      c=c+1;
      cout<<"   "<<a;
    }
  }
  cout<<"\n\n\n" << c << endl;
  return(0);
}
```